# Fechar Menu com SlideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá galera estou com um menu para mobile "hambúrguer" e estou querendo que ele feche quando aperto em algum link do menu.

Código HTML do menu:

```
<div class="menu">
    <button class="hamburger">
        <img src="images/responsive/cel_retrato/ham.png"/>
    </button>
    <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    <ul clas="menuMM">
        <a href="#topo"><li>HOME</li></a>
        <a href="#pixel"><li>SOBRE</li></a>
        <a href="#servicos"><li>SERVIÇOS</li></a>
        <a href="#projetos"><li>PORTFÓLIO</li></a>
        <a href="#contactM"><li>CONTATO</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".menu" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $( ".hamburger" ).hide();
        $( ".cross" ).show();
    });
});
$( ".cross" ).click(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $( ".cross" ).hide();
        $( ".hamburger" ).show();
    });
});
```

Para fechar o menu estou ultilizando está lógica, porém não está funcionando.

```
$( ".menuMM" ).click(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $( ".cross" ).hide();
        $( ".hamburger" ).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Caro, em sua lógica, ao clicar em `.menuMM` ele executa o `slideToggle();` no `.menu` onde contem `.cross` e `.hamburguer`, seguindo isso, deveria esconder todos os elementos dentro de `.menu`. O que aparenta não estar funcionando ?

Comment: Quando clico em algum menu ele não ta escondendo o MENU.

Comment: Sua intenção é de quando clicar no `.menu` esconder o `.menuMM` mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrija o atributo `clas="menuMM"` para `class="menuMM"`, provavelmente isto está causando o erro. Fiz um exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze14psjr/1/) e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: nossa nem vi, obrigado amigo rs